# How to use the env variable of the image to set another env variable in docker compose?

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables

Following is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  test-build:
    image: docker-hardened-ol8-openjdk17
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - "C:/checkouts:/opt/checkouts"
    ports:
      - 9001:9001
    environment:
    - JAVA_17_HOME=${JAVA_HOME:?err}
```

The *docker-hardened-ol8-openjdk17* image has Java 17 and the *JAVA_HOME* environment variable. I need to set the *JAVA_17_HOME* environment variable to the same as *JAVA_HOME* from the image. But when I run *docker compose up*, it takes the *JAVA_HOME* value set in my machine (host machine).

I read the https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/ and https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/ pages. Even these pages mention that -

> Compose uses the variable values from the shell environment in which docker-compose is run.

Is there a way I can specify docker-compose to use the image's environment variable instead of the host machine's?

Comment: You could use the `export` command: `command: export JAVA_17_HOME=$JAVA_HOME && tail -f /dev/null`

Comment: There are many such environment variables I need to export into my container that are derived using the environment variables from the image. So I feel this isn't the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

I could work around this using a Dockerfile along with the docker-compose.yml config file in the same directory. I moved the image part to the Dockerfile, and declared all the environment variables in the Dockerfile.

**docker-compose.yml -**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  test-build:
    build:
      context: .
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - "C:/checkouts:/opt/checkouts"
    ports:
    - 9001:9001
```

**Dockerfile -**

```
FROM docker-hardened-ol8-openjdk17
ENV JAVA_17_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
ENV BUILD_HOME=/opt/checkouts/
WORKDIR $BUILD_HOME
```